# reindex rule product catalog

Tags: magento2, reindex, catalog-price-rules

sorry for my language...
I have a little problem with magento 2.3 . I use product catalog rules to create discounts for groups of users. once every day or two, there is no specific time or in any case I cannot understand why, the product rules no longer work. If I connect with a user who is associated with a group with rules, I do not see any product discounts. The only solution is to "reindex" and "flush" magento from terminal.

I created a cron job that reindexes and flushes cache every day, but that's not enough.

Every time I have to receive messages from my customers who do not see the discounts and at that moment I have to reindex.

Do you know which event triggers the loss of the rules ?? how can i solve?

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you describe it is typical to your cron table being stuck.

It seems your database uses a prefix `mg_`

If you login to mysql and do the following `select * from mg_cron_schedule where status not in ('success', 'pending');`

If the result shows many results, then you will likely need to check the health of your cron processes.

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ran the query and these results came out.

the messages column says:

id 792: " SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'aa_mg3.mg_magento_bulk' doesn't exist, query was: DELETE FROM mg_magento_bulk WHERE (start_time <= '2019-02-08 12:53:14') "

id 831: " SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'aa_mg3.mg_inventory_stock' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT mg_inventory_stock.stock_id FROM mg_inventory_stock"

What should I do? is this the cause of why i have to reindex and flush manually?

Comment: I think I understand the problem. Wrong the name of the tables or schema.

How do I change the cron to point to different tables?

If I fix these two problems does it fix the catalog rule problem?

Comment: I can't tell you that. If you have changed your system, it is not possibe to guess what you need, sorry

Comment: is there any way to edit the magento cron that produces this error?

Comment: yes, check log files and fix the error that you find in your log

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Thanks for the reply. I ran the query and these results came out.

the messages column says:

id 792: " SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'aa_mg3.mg_magento_bulk' doesn't exist, query was: DELETE FROM `mg_magento_bulk` WHERE (start_time <= '2019-02-08 12:53:14') "

id 831: " SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'aa_mg3.mg_inventory_stock' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `mg_inventory_stock`.`stock_id` FROM `mg_inventory_stock`"

What should I do?
is this the cause of why i have to reindex and flush manually?